# How do I change the font in this Bootstrap template?

Tags: css, font-face

[Link to Github Source](https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-clean-blog).

I've tried changing the font-family for each h1 and body, but nothing's coming up. Obviously doing something stupid, but can't seem to figure it out. Driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to share the specific code if you want a quick response either paste the code or add js fiddle. Time consuming to navigate through the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
body{
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

You can change just some propriets of h1 fonts to, just use for example

```
h1{
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

create a custom css file and put them below the bootstrap css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/clean-blog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/mystyle.css">
```

Your css will overwrite the bootstrap css that is in your own css

Answer (score 0):

you can customize bootstrap via it is own site, and override.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/